# OCR Logger Could Not be Resolved-Java

Tags: java, ocr

So I am trying to get an OCR working for a bigger project that reads characters from an image and I am following this you tube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aEMSxiXctPk
I did everything in the video and still cannot get it to work. I looked on this forum about the error I am getting, but it looks like their projects are different so I think they need different jars than I would. I have all of the jars from the video or at least I think I do. Any ways, the issue in java delivered this message.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The type org.slf4j.Logger cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
    org.slf4j.Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    LoggerFactory cannot be resolved
    The method setDatapath(String) of type Tesseract must override a superclass method
```

This is my code:

```
package Tess4j;
import java.io.*;
import net.sourceforge.tess4j.*;
import org.slf4j.*;


public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        File imageFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Sean\\workspace\\Bigno Tracker\\Images\\eurotext.png");
        ITesseract instance=new Tesseract();
        instance.setDatapath("C:\\Users\\Sean\\workspace\\Bigno Tracker\\tessdata");
        try {
            String result=instance.doOCR(imageFile);
            System.out.println(result);
        }catch (TesseractException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

This is an image of my screen that shows the jars I have.

[image]

So what am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177788/discussion-on-question-by-bob-g-ocr-logger-could-not-be-resolved-java).

Answer (score 0):

I don’t really understand your question but, I’ve done some work with OCR Engines in the past.. ABBYY hass a good one that’s really easy to integrate!

P.S Did a little research, check to see if you have all the appropriate dependencies for your OCR engine version

Cheers

Comment: The answer “I don’t understand what you are asking” isn’t a justifiable answer. Don’t attempt an answer on a poorly asked question, as it will probably never get an effective answer and your answer may be removed with the question itself.

Comment: You're not exactly providing an answer, Nick has done better than you in my opinion, but still doesn't help much as I want to use tessi.

Comment: The reason I’m not providing an answer is because your question ISN’T COMPLETE. It’s simple, it doesn’t contain enough detail, and it’s too broad to be able to determine an EXACT answer. I’m sorry you aren’t happy with what I’m saying, but your question is not good enough for an answer.

Comment: I literally gave you the specific error code, this tells me you didn't read my post fully. Go back and read my post fully. My question is complete, you're just not seeing it. Go back and please read my post or leave and I am sure someone else can help me better. Thanks for trying.

Comment: Got it I’ll throw it in the comments

Comment: Thanks @NickMikal for being civil about my comment. Imm glad at least one person can accept constructive criticism.

Comment: I can accept constructive criticism, but it has to be correct criticism. Its like if person 1 said 1+1=3 and person 2 said here is constructive criticism where the answer is 4. Person 2 failed to give good criticism. He should have said 2.

Comment: I have same problem as well? If anybody knows what is missing please tell us?